# Using @Model in VB ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I am working through the tutorial "Getting Started with EF6 using MVC 5" on http://www.asp.net and converting to VB as I go.

In the third tutorial "Sorting, Filtering and Paging" (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) there is a section "Add Paging Links to the Student Index View" where the C# code is

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Student>
...
```

I convert this statement to
    @Model PagedList.IPagedlist(Of Student)

this compiles but I get no syntax colouring and the output on the web page shows
PagedList.PagedList`1[ContosoUniversity.Student] PagedList.IPagedlist(Of Student)

how should I convert this to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@ModelType`, instead of `@Model`, for `.vbhtml` files.